# Json queries mysql 5.7 keep failing in HHVM travis-ci

Tags: json, pdo, travis-ci, hhvm, mysql-5.7

I am trying to use HHVM with mysql 5.7. All the queries which use JSON columns fail with `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`. The queries which don't access JSON columns work fine. How do I manage to get these queries working? Doesn't HHVM have support for mysql 5.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with the hhvm PDO implementation. For me `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true` fixed it.